# Expression Engine Module tables and datasort

Tags: codeigniter, datatables, expressionengine

I am currently working on a custom module add-on and I wanted to be able to use sorting and filtering on the a table in my control panel admin. I am using the EE table class and form helper. I'm trying to follow the [documentation here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/usage/table.html#example-improving-usability-for-large-amounts-of-data) for setting it up, but when I call try to call the '_datasource' method in my class I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Content_publish::_datasource() in /home/public_html/system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Table.php on line 162
```

I have a feeling it's a scoping issue, but in the table class '$this->EE->table->datasource()' method you are supposed to just pass a string value with the name of your datasource function which is what I'm doing.

I don't seem to be the only one with this issue. There are more details and code examples on [this EE Discussion forum thread](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/228443/)

The documentation is not really clear. I also tried looking at EE's own comments module to see if i could figure it out, but no luck. Anyone have experience with this?

Here is the method I'm calling:

```
$data = $this->EE->table->datasource('_datasource');
```

And this is my function in my class:

```
function _datasource()
{
     // ....
     // $query comes from DB result set code above.
     // I have omitted it here for brevity

    $datarows = array();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $key => $row)
    {
    $datarows[] = array(
        'entry_id'          => $row['entry_id'],
        'date'   => date('Y-m-d',$row['entry_date']),
        'author'          => $row['screen_name'],
        'payment'         => $payment_amount,
        'status'             => $status,
        'title'          => $edit_href.$row['title']."</a>"
      );
    }

    return $datarows;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `datasource` callback function must be on your `Module_mcp` class (looking at your forum thread you are trying to use it on a plugin which would explain the error).

If you want to put the datasource method on a different class, then just add this line right before you call `datasource()` to trick the table library into using the correct class:

```
// ensure table callbacks use this class rather than our MCP file
$this->EE->_mcp_reference =& $this;
$data = $this->EE->table->datasource('_datasource');
```

The `table` and `form_validation` libraries are the only two which use the special `_mcp_reference` variable, so I can't see any side effects to changing it, and have successfully done this in at least two modules.

On a side note, if you want a good example of how to use the built in tablesorter, take a look at `system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/members.php`. The documentation is pretty bad, but the source code always tells the truth :)

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Posting in that specific thread may have lead to the confusion, but my _datasource function is in my module's Module_mcp class for sure. I'm sure I'm just doing something silly and having a good example to go off will likely prove to be the answer. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I'll try to post an update to let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Your datasort method may be on your Module_mcp class, but are you calling datasort from your mcp file, or from a plugin class? Probably best to `print_r($this->EE->_mcp_reference)` just in case and make sure it points to your current class.

Comment: The print_r returned:
    
    `object(Tmo_payments_mcp)[424]
        public 'version' => string '2.0.0' (length=5)
        private '_base_url' => string 'artsys?S=24bc4a880ab8ce6a4dd458d7f893dc8ebc181c09&amp;D=cp&amp;C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=tmo_payments' (length=124)
        private '_form_base' => string 'C=addons_modules&amp;M=show_module_cp&amp;module=tmo_payments' (length=61)
        private 'EE' => &
        ...`

Comment: Sorry I guess comments have limited code formatting. [Here is a more readable version](https://gist.github.com/4122647)

So I asume since the object is my Module and the _datasource function is in that MCP class then I assume I'm in the right place?

Comment: Yip, the object(Tmo_payments_mcp) bit looks right to me. PS if you're still stuck and have any more you can add to the question to help us solve it, it would be awesome if you could repost on the dedicated [EE stack exchange site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/). We need good questions like this to get it launched. Sing out if you need an invite :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been having issues too and have a mixed solution of generate() and datasource working. Here it is here:

In my mcp file:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', lang('my_module_name'));
    $data = $this->EE->table->datasource('_datasource');

    return $this->EE->load->view('index', $data, TRUE);
}

public function _datasource()
{
    $headers = array(
        'name'  => array('header' => 'Name'),
        'color' => array('header' => 'Color'),
        'size'  => array('header' => 'Size')
    );

    $rows = array(
        array('name' => 'Fred', 'color' => 'Blue',  'size' => 'Small'),
        array('name' => 'Mary', 'color' => 'Red',   'size' => 'Large'),
        array('name' => 'John', 'color' => 'Green', 'size' => 'Medium'),
    );

    return array(
        'rows' => $rows,
        'headers' => $headers
    );
}
```

In my index view file:

```
$this->table->set_columns($headers);
$this->table->set_data($rows);
echo $this->table->generate();
```

Seems to be working at the moment and I've not tried pagination yet, but sorting works.